# Как при помощи Webpack скопировать структуру директорий?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

При помощи следующего кода в файле `webpack.mix.js` пытаюсь скопировать все файлы, директории и поддиректории из `bower_components/strike-pro-frontend` в `public/`.

```
// Copy frontend public folders
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/css/**/*', 'public/css');
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/fonts/**/*', 'public/fonts');
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/images/**/*', 'public/images');
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/img/**/*', 'public/img');
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/js/**/*', 'public/js');
```

Собственно вот наглядно структура директорий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, при копировании игнорируется структура директорий, а также копируются не все файлы, а только те которые расположены по маске `**/*`.

Плюс ко всему в итоге всё скопированные файлы помещаются в одну директорию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как нужно копировать файлы, директории и поддиректории, чтобы сохранилась структура? Возможно следует использовать маску другого вида?

P.S. таких директорий в проекте очень много, прописывать отдельно `mix.copy()` для каждой группы поддиректорий не вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение найдено!**

Для того, чтобы сохранить структуру копируемых директорий требовалось передать в функцию `mix.copy()` третий параметр `false`.

Согласно сигнатуре функции `mix.copy(from,to,flatten)` - 3й параметр `flatten` по умолчанию стоит в `true`, т.е. все копируемые файлы из директорий и поддиректорий `from` будут скопированы в директорию `to` без сохранения структуры директорий.

В моём случае решение выглядит так:

```
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/css', 'public/css', false);
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/fonts', 'public/fonts', false);
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/images', 'public/images', false);
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/img', 'public/img', false);
mix.copy('bower_components/strike-pro-frontend/js', 'public/js', false);
```

**Источники:**

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/copy-folder-structure-with-laravel-mix-laravel-54
- https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/540